# Rails twitter bootstrap change well background to image

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm working on a rails app and using twitter bootstrap to speed up the process.  However I'm trying to change the .well class to an image instead of just a color and I'm not finding the right variable.

I have tried:

```
@wellBackground: asset-url('path_to_file');
```

and thought well maybe it would be:

```
@wellBackgroundImage: asset-url('path_to_file');
```

neither seem to get me where I want to be.  Any help would be appreciated.

So I pulled it out into it's own css file, but I'm still not getting the image.

```
.well.sidebar-nav{
background: #C4C4C4 url('/app/assets/images/tweed.png') repeat-x top left ;
color: #FFFFFF;
 }
```

However I'm still not getting the image in the background.  Maybe a path in RoR issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS approach will work.

Double check your selector .well.sidebar-nar is correct and that there isn't background styling for this div coming from somewhere else.

If everything is good there, then it's probably because the path to the tweed.png file is incorrect. Remember for a CSS background image, the path is relative to the CSS file, not relative to your website root.

A [working example](http://www.bootply.com/68590)

Good luck!

Comment: yeah I know it's probably a path issue, but I think it has to do with getting the path in a RoR app.. Never had this issue before in a standard Html site. Thanks for your input though. :)

Comment: Have you tried using the error console or web inspector in Chrome / Safari ?